# Gradle: Project "x" not found in root project "myProject"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, touchdb

Having upgraded to Android Studio from Eclipse I wanted to update my TouchDB library which is now [Coubasebase-lite-android](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android). I removed TouchDB from my project, git cloned couchbase-lite-android added to my project in Android Studio via File -> Import Module.

Everything looks good in the IDE and all the references look good. But when I try and compile it I receive the error in Android Studio: `Gradle: Project "x" not found in root project "myProject"`  "x" being each module(?) inside couchbaselite...i.e CBLite, CBLiteEktrop etc

I really don't know where to start with this one?

Here's my project tree:

```
myProject
---myProject
---CouchbaseLiteProject
------CBLite
------CBLiteEktorp
------Gradle
------.Gradle
------gradlew
------CouchbaseLiteProject
---------build
---------libs
---------src
```

here's the contents of `gradlew` from CouchBaseLiteProject:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##############################################################################
##
##  Gradle start up script for UN*X
##
##############################################################################

# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""

APP_NAME="Gradle"
APP_BASE_NAME=`basename "$0"`

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that value.
MAX_FD="maximum"

warn ( ) {
    echo "$*"
}

die ( ) {
    echo
    echo "$*"
    echo
    exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false
msys=false
darwin=false
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN* )
    cygwin=true
    ;;
  Darwin* )
    darwin=true
    ;;
  MINGW* )
    msys=true
    ;;
esac

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched.
if $cygwin ; then
    [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
fi

# Attempt to set APP_HOME
# Resolve links: $0 may be a link
PRG="$0"
# Need this for relative symlinks.
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
    if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
        PRG="$link"
    else
        PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
    fi
done
SAVED="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`/" >&-
APP_HOME="`pwd -P`"
cd "$SAVED" >&-

CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" ] ; then
        # IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
    else
        JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    fi
    if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
        die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
    fi
else
    JAVACMD="java"
    which java >/dev/null 2>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi

# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can.
if [ "$cygwin" = "false" -a "$darwin" = "false" ] ; then
    MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        if [ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" ] ; then
            MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
        fi
        ulimit -n $MAX_FD
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
        fi
    else
        warn "Could not query maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi
fi

# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the dock
if $darwin; then
    GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\" \"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin ; then
    APP_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$APP_HOME"`
    CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`

    # We build the pattern for arguments to be converted via cygpath
    ROOTDIRSRAW=`find -L / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null`
    SEP=""
    for dir in $ROOTDIRSRAW ; do
        ROOTDIRS="$ROOTDIRS$SEP$dir"
        SEP="|"
    done
    OURCYGPATTERN="(^($ROOTDIRS))"
    # Add a user-defined pattern to the cygpath arguments
    if [ "$GRADLE_CYGPATTERN" != "" ] ; then
        OURCYGPATTERN="$OURCYGPATTERN|($GRADLE_CYGPATTERN)"
    fi
    # Now convert the arguments - kludge to limit ourselves to /bin/sh
    i=0
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        CHECK=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "$OURCYGPATTERN" -`
        CHECK2=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "^-"`                                 ### Determine if an option

        if [ $CHECK -ne 0 ] && [ $CHECK2 -eq 0 ] ; then                    ### Added a condition
            eval `echo args$i`=`cygpath --path --ignore --mixed "$arg"`
        else
            eval `echo args$i`="\"$arg\""
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    case $i in
        (0) set -- ;;
        (1) set -- "$args0" ;;
        (2) set -- "$args0" "$args1" ;;
        (3) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" ;;
        (4) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" ;;
        (5) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" ;;
        (6) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" ;;
        (7) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" ;;
        (8) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" ;;
        (9) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" "$args8" ;;
    esac
fi

# Split up the JVM_OPTS And GRADLE_OPTS values into an array, following the shell quoting and substitution rules
function splitJvmOpts() {
    JVM_OPTS=("$@")
}
eval splitJvmOpts $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $GRADLE_OPTS
JVM_OPTS[${#JVM_OPTS[*]}]="-Dorg.gradle.appname=$APP_BASE_NAME"

exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain "$@"
```

`
There is no gradlew file under myProject as it was originally a Eclipse project

**update**
following on from buzeeg's advice and not being able to export my project from Eclipse to generate the gradle files I decided to create a new project in Android Studio and manually copy my original project files into it, so Android Studio would create the gradle files for me.

After importing couchbase-lite-android as a module and trying to build the project I get exactly the same errors as I originally encountered. `Gradle: Project "x" not found in root project "myProject"` "x" relating to all the sub modules (?) under the CouchbaseLiteProject tree...

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file and explain us your project structure ?

Comment: ok thanks will add it to my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278875/error-project-app-not-found-in-root-project-projectname/56723341#56723341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couchbase-Lite is fast moving development right now - and now moved entirely over to Android Studio.  Really one of the first projects I've seen be so quick in abandoning Eclipse. Even using Android Studio 0.2.2 I'm having problems getting it to integrate with my app.

I suggest you get working the GrocerySync app that they publish as a sample. It's using maven integration to the database files (basically goes after the jars).  As for direct integration approach - the developers seem to be most on OS X right now and on Ubuntu 13.04 I'm having problems getting Android Studio to locate the files and not complain that symbols are missing.

The good news is that with the Android Studio build I can use direct integration and compile at the shell.  Have you tried using gradlew to compile at the shell level?

Comment: Didn't try gradlew, gradle is still completely new to me. I'm also on Ubuntu 13.04 and took your advice and got the GrocerySync app up and running. Was then going to rebuild my app on top of the GrocerySync project once that was working. Then realised Couchbase-Lite has a min sdk requirements of honeycomb while nearly a third of my users are using pre honeycomb devices. *sigh*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your Eclipse project in order to have a build file (*build.gradle*) [Migrating from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) :

> 1. Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).
> 2. In Eclipse, select File > Export.
> 3. In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.
> 4. Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.
>
> Your selected project remains in the same location but now contains a build.gradle file and is ready for Android Studio.

Then, Android Studio will be able to build your project using this *build.gradle* file.

Comment: Got up to number 4. click finish but nothing happens, the build files dialog window doesn't disappear and on checking my project folder no gradle files are created. 

The project does come up with a crap load of build errors in eclipse, would this prevent the project being exported?

Comment: This is starting to remind me why I couldn't wait to get away from Eclipse. Too many times wanting to throw my laptop against the wall because of it. Can I generate the required gradle files without having to touch eclipse?

Comment: Perhaps you can try to create manually the build.gradle file. There are a lot of information in the documentation : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide You can also look at other tutorial, like for exemple the 4 last post on http://www.stylingandroid.com which deals with Gradle